# How can I find the corresponding node in xml using Vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

This is my xml. I have Id 1490. How can I find the corresponding node in xml using Vb.net
**I can't use LINQ**

```
    <Abc>
     <A> 
      <Name>T</Name>
      <Id>1232</Id>
      <Val>140</Val>
      <Branch>
       <A>
       <Name>T.1</Name>
      <Id>1343</Id>
      <Val>14qw0</Val>
       </A>
       <A>
       <Name>T.2</Name>
      <Id>1090</Id>
      <Val>14qwd0</Val>
       <Branch>
       <A>
       <Name>T.2.2</Name>
        <Id>1490</Id>
        <Val>rt56</Val>
       </A>
       </Branch>
     </A>
</Branch>
     </A>
     <A>
       <Name>TA</Name>
        <Id>1339</Id>
        <Val>uiui</Val>
        <Branch>
        <A>
        <Name>TA.1</Name>
            <Id>1338</Id>
            <Val>bije</Val>
        </A>
        </Branch>
    </A>
    </Abc>
```

Comment: You really have nested `<A>` tags?

Comment: That Xml isn't valid as well. There's an unmatched Branch tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the selectNodes with the XmlDocument. Follow this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa335969

A vb.net example can be seen here, with loading the xml string in a document, and then selecting nodes : http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/349552/getting-single-node-by-id-then-get-childnode-innertext

Comment: Something like this 

Dim n As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Abc/A[@Id='1940']"), while doc is an XML Document.